# What algorithms exist for accurately estimating ETA on data transfer?

Tags: algorithm

This feels like something that ought to have had some significant statistical analysis.

Calculating the ETA on anything from a download to disk copy [has always been a problem](https://xkcd.com/612/) because the process usually ends up with random (stochastic?) data transfer rates throughout the process.  Using the trivial calculation `time taken * (data remaining / data transferred)` produces surprisingly variable results.

Are there any algorithms better than the above calculation which produce stable and "realistic" ETA?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to use a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) to estimate the average transfer rate over a window of time, rather than using the most recent instantaneous estimate of the transfer rate.  You will have to choose a suitable window length.

You may prefer a [weighted moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Weighted_moving_average), which is a moving average where the instantaneous measurements within the window are not all weighted equally. Typically you would weight more recent measurements higher than older measurements.

These parameters (window length and weights) are a matter of judgement.
However, if you want to take it very seriously, you could collect measurements from real data transfers, and train the model parameters using a machine learning algorithm.

Comment: Wouldn't a window stretching all the way back to the beginning of the transfer be the most accurate? But it seems this is the one that leads to wildly fluctuating estimates.

Comment: Not necessarily. Suppose a connection usually runs at 1Mb/s, but on rare occasions drops to 1Kb/s for an indeterminate period. There is no *a priori* reason to suppose that the proportion of future time in which the connection is slow will equal the proportion of past time (during this particular transfer) in which the connection was slow.

Comment: The opposite is also true, just because you've been running 1Mb/s for a while doesn't mean the speed won't suddenly drop to 1Kb/s.

Comment: Indeed. But if the current transfer did slow down at some point and has come back up now, then it's not unreasonable to say that after a certain period (i.e. the window length) of the connection being back up, the issue seems to be resolved so you can expect full speed for the rest of the transfer.

Comment: By the way, I think the wildly varying times reported by xkcd's Windows file transfer dialog are caused by using just the most recent instantaneous transfer rate, not by using an average over the whole transfer so far.

Comment: @kaya3 could you expand on the "weighted moving average"?  Particularly if you have any suggestions on weight distributions (half normal?, half Gaussian? etc.).

Comment: A weighted moving average is a moving average where the instantaneous measurements within the window are not all weighted equally. Typically you would weight more recent measurements higher than older measurements. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Weighted_moving_average

Comment: @kaya3 on the subject of the windows file transfer.  Certainly they previously used a poorly chosen algorithm / parameters for the particular task.  File transfer happens to be a particularly tricky task to predict because it's really two things: file content transfer and file meta-information transfer.  The old mechanism appeared focused only on the content and not the meta.  Since meta-information per content varies wildly (one file name per a few bytes, to one file name per a few gigabytes), it never had a chance of being right in any situation. Not to mention HD seek times on non SSD HDs.

Comment: @PhilipCouling how often is the meta-data not a tiny percentage of the data being copied?  And if it is large in comparison, how often is it so large that you need to worry about its progress?

Comment: @MarkRansom If you are copying a large directory it can be responsible for a very large proportion of the time.  Creatnig a single (empty) file in windows takes a lot of time - equivalent too several kilobytes.  On HDD (not SSD) it also requires several head seeks which can be quivalent to writing 100s of KB of block data.  So copying thousands of < 1KB files is *a lot* slower than copying the same file data packed into a single file.